# PowerBI DAX: Date periods identification formula issue on previous 3 months

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a sales data set and want to create a calculated column to be used as legend on graphs and also use as filter of dates but I'm struggling on with the part that identificate the previous 3 months before the last month.

My formula looks like this:

```
Period identification = 
IF('Base'[Date]=CALCULATE(MAX('Base'[Date]);FILTER('Base';'Base'[FYTD]="FY1920"));"LM";

IF(
    AND('Base'[Date]>=
            DATEADD(CALCULATE(MAX('Base'[Date]);FILTER('Base';'Base'[FYTD]="FY1920"));-3;MONTH);
        'Base'[Date]<CALCULATE(MAX('Base'[Date]);FILTER('Base';'Base'[FYTD]="FY1920")));"P3M";

IF('Base'[Date]=CALCULATE(MAX('Base'[Date]);FILTER('Base';'Base'[FYTD]="FY1819"));"LM YA";"OTHERS")))
```

The first IF() (Last Month - LM) and the last (Last Month Year Ago - LM YA) are working fine. I just can't find a way of PBI accept the kind of calculus I'm trying to do in the middle to identificate the previous 3 months before the last month.

*The [FYTD] is another calculated column that identificate the corresponding fiscal year of the [Date].[Month]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make this much easier using the handy [`EOMONTH` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/eomonth-function-dax) to move through time.

Try something like this where `RefDate` is the date that you want to use to calculate dates relative to. I'm using the end last month.

```
Period =
VAR RefDate = EOMONTH ( TODAY (), -1 )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        EOMONTH ( Base[Date], 0 ) = EOMONTH ( RefDate, 0 ), "LM",
        Base[Date] > EOMONTH ( RefDate, -4 ), "P3M",
        EOMONTH ( Base[Date], 0 ) = EOMONTH ( RefDate, -12 ), "LM YA",
        "OTHERS"
    )
```

Note:[`SWITCH(TRUE(),...)`](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/the-diabolical-genius-of-switch-true/) returns the result for the first condition that evaluates to `TRUE()`.

Comment: Actually I really want the last month on formula to be related the FYTD calculated column and not to current date (TODAY()) because sometimes we don't have the last month data on time but your rational is perfect and with a few adaption it is working fine. Thank you!